# Nothing read from Azure Blob storage after downloading file in stream data

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

I'm fetching file from Azure blob storage with the following code but `downloadedData` is always empty string. I referred this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobasyncclientbase?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-specialized-blobasyncclientbase-download()) to read the file from the location. The file is not empty and does contain values. I tried with multiple type of files - text,pdf etc. But for all `downloadedData`  is empty. How can I fix this issue?

```java
      BlobAsyncClient blobAsyncClient = containerClient.getBlobAsyncClient("abc/file1.txt");
            ByteArrayOutputStream downloadData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            blobAsyncClient.downloadStream().subscribe(piece -> {
                try {
                    downloadData.write(piece.array());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling an Async method, but not awaiting for the completion.

You can call the .blockLast() method, or use the doOnComplete().

```
blobAsyncClient.downloadStream().subscribe(piece -> {
    try {
        downloadData.write(piece.array());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
}).blockLast();
```

or

```
blobAsyncClient.downloadStream().doOnNext(piece -> {
    try {
        downloadData.write(piece.array());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
}).doOnComplete(() -> {
    // This ensures that the downloadData is not accessed until it's fully populated
}).subscribe();
```